# Using the Poisson approximation to estimate the number of trials required to guarantee at least one success

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that on average, out of $N$ trials, $q$ succeed. $q$ is much smaller than $N$. For a concrete example, suppose $N = 100$ and $q = 2$.

Let $n$ be the number of trials run in a particular experiment. How large should $n$ be to ensure with probability $x$ that there is at least 1 success? For a concrete example, suppose that $x = 0.95$.

The probability that there are $k$ successes in $n$ trials might be approximated using the binomial distribution with probability parameter $p = q/N$.

The probability that there are is at least $1$ success is given by:

$$ x = 1 - P(\text{$0$ successes}) = 1 - {n \choose 0} p^0 (1 - p)^{n - 0} = 1 - (1 - p)^n $$

Solving for $n$:

$$ (1 - p)^n = 1 - x $$

Using our concrete values, we get:

$$ n \approx 150 $$

Let us now try the Poisson approximation approach. Let $\lambda = np$. Then:

$$ 1 - \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda 0}}{0!} = x \Leftrightarrow 1 - \lambda = x \Leftrightarrow \frac{1 - x}{p} = n$$

Recalling that $p = q/N$:

$$ \frac{N(1 - x)}{q} = n $$

Using our concrete values for $N$, $x$ and $q$:

$$ n \approx 3 $$

**There is already an issue with what I have done so far, since the Poisson approximation gives a result that is totally non-sensical. What am I doing wrong?**

Going further, I want to try and bound the error in the estimate for $n$ that I get from the Poisson approximation. Tccuracy bounds on the Poisson approximation for the binomial distribution state that if $X \sim \text{Bin}(M, r)$, and $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(Mr)$:

$$ |P(X \in \mathbb{N}) - P(Y \in \mathbb{N})| \leq Mr^2 $$

since $\mathbb{N}$ is the set over which both Poisson and binomial distributions are defined (naturals include $0$).

I am a bit confused by the $P(X \in \mathbb{N})$ bit, and not quite sure how to use the bound to estimate how good $n$ is. Can you help?

Comment: How is $(1-p)^n=1-x$ not an easy equation to solve? By taking logarithms, $n=\frac{\log(1-x)}{\log(1-p)}$.

Comment: @Math1000 Easy to solve without a calculator, I suppose (this is a modified version of a question which explicitly asks for the answerer to use a Poisson approximation)?

Comment: I didn't need a calculator to solve that. Simply take the logarithm of both sides and divide by $\log(1-p)$. Basic algebra. I don't know why you are invoking these complicated estimates, unless I am completely misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @Math1000 The question had actual values $N$, $q$ and $p$. Pretty sure you need a calculator or a table to get log values. Plus, you can just view using the Poisson approximation as a constraint/an exercise. We're not talking about the fastest/most efficient way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miscalculated the probability in the Poisson case. Indeed, since the Poisson probability is given by
$$
\mathbb P\bigl(\textrm{Poisson}(\lambda)=k\bigr)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!},
$$
we have that the probability of no successes is $$\frac{\lambda^0e^{-\lambda}}{0!}=e^{-\lambda},$$
not $\lambda$ as you have written.
Thus, the Poisson approximation yields
$$
1-e^{-\lambda}=x\iff \lambda=-\ln(1-x)
$$
Since $\lambda=np=\frac{nq}{N}$, we obtain that
$$
n=\frac{\lambda N}{q}=\frac{-N\ln(1-x)}{q}=-50\ln(.05)\approx 149.787
$$

As a point of comparison, the true value of $n$ (without making any approximation) is
$$
n=\frac{\ln(1-x)}{\ln(1-q/N)}=\frac{\ln(.05)}{\ln(.98)}\approx 148.284
$$
The difference between these two expressions is that in the exact expression the denominator is $\ln(1-q/N)$, which in the approximation is replaced by its first Taylor approximation, $-q/N$. (In general, the first Taylor approximation of $\ln(1+y)$ is simply $y$, and this is the case when $y=-q/N$.)